# does bootcamp provide the best drivers for windows 7, or should i install the ones windows 7 suggests for me?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, boot-camp

I'm running windows 7 via bootcamp on my MBP (the model that was newest in summer 2009). Bootcamp is up to date. Windows 7 just suggested I install a new driver for my nvidia card. However, I was under the impression bootcamp provided the most optimal drivers for windows 7  to run on my MBP's hardware. Should I stick with what bootcamp gives for my video driver, or update to the one windows 7 suggests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 7 does something that Windows XP and Vista were supposed to do but never actually did: It fetches the newest drivers from vendors *for* you.

It's best to use the drivers provided by Windows 7 after doing a Windows Update.

Click the Start button and type *Windows Update* into the search box.

Click on *Windows Update* to open the Update control panel.

Look for *Optional Updates* on this window in blue.

Click there to see a list of optional updates, including new drivers.

Click the check boxes to select the drivers you want to update, then go ahead with the update.

Finally, restart your Windows 7 to finish the updates.

Comment: In some rare instances, you'll want to download the driver directly from the manufacturer. One thing that comes to mind is the nVidia and ATI video card drivers. The Windows driver lacks a lot of functionality and performance compared to the drivers provided directly from the manufacturer.